# Code to merge sorted linked lists in java

Tags: java, programming-challenge, linked-list

Since I am using Hackerrank codepair, I have to resort to inner classes.
Please review the code and let me know if this can be improved.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class LinkedListMerge {

    private List<LinkedList<Integer>> listsToMerge;
    private LinkedList<Integer> mergedList;

    public LinkedListMerge() {
        listsToMerge = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
        listsToMerge.add(new LinkedList(new Integer[]{3, 5, 7, 10, 11}));
        listsToMerge.add(new LinkedList(new Integer[]{13, 25, 72, 101, 111}));
        listsToMerge.add(new LinkedList(new Integer[]{12, 15, 17, 110, 112}));

        mergedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }

    public void mergeLists() {
        PriorityQueue<ValueIterator> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<ValueIterator>(listsToMerge.size());

        for(LinkedList<Integer> linkedList : listsToMerge) {
            Iterator<Node<Integer>> currentIterator = linkedList.iterator();
            priorityQueue.add(new ValueIterator(currentIterator.next().getValue(), currentIterator));
        }

        while(priorityQueue.peek() != null) {
            ValueIterator minElement = priorityQueue.poll();
            mergedList.add((Integer)minElement.getValue());
            if(minElement.getIterator().hasNext()) {
                Node<Integer> nextElement = ( Node<Integer>)minElement.getIterator().next();
                priorityQueue.add(new ValueIterator(nextElement.getValue(), minElement.getIterator()));
            }
        }

    }

    public LinkedList getMergedList() {
        return mergedList;
    }

    private class ValueIterator<K extends Comparable> implements Comparable {
        K value;
        Iterator<K> iterator;

        public ValueIterator(K value, Iterator<K> iterator) {
            this.value = value;
            this.iterator = iterator;
        }

        public K getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public Iterator<K> getIterator() {
            return iterator;
        }

        @Override 
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            return value.compareTo(((ValueIterator)o).getValue());
        }
    }

    public class LinkedList<K extends Comparable> {
        private Node<K> head = null;
        private Node<K> tail = null;

        public LinkedList() {

        }

        public LinkedList(K[] array) {
            head = new Node(array[0], null);

            Node<K> currentPointer = head;
            for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                currentPointer.setNext(new Node(array[i], null));
                currentPointer = currentPointer.next();
            }
            tail = currentPointer;
        }

        public void add(K element) {
            if(head == null) {
                head = new Node(element, null);
                tail = head;
            } else {
                tail.setNext(new Node(element, null));
                tail = tail.next();
            }
        }

        public Iterator<Node<K>> iterator() {
            return new Itr(head);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
            Iterator<Node<K>> itr = iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                Node<K> current = itr.next();
                str.append(current.getValue().toString());
                str.append("->");
            }
            return str.toString();
        }

        private class Itr implements Iterator<Node<K>> {
            private Node<K> cursor;

            public Itr(Node<K> start) {
                cursor = start;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return cursor !=null;
            }

            @Override
            public Node<K> next() {
                Node<K> currentElement = cursor;
                cursor = cursor.next();
                return currentElement;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Operation");
            }
        }

    }

    private class Node<K extends Comparable> {
        K data;
        Node next;

        public Node( K data, Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node node) {
            next = node;
        }

        public Node<K> next() {
            return next;
        }

        public K getValue() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LinkedListMerge llm = new LinkedListMerge();
        llm.mergeLists();
        System.out.println(llm.getMergedList().toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get great answers.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simplifying the implementation

That's a lot of code for something that could be done simpler.

Consider this alternative implementation:

- Given the head nodes of two lists
- While both heads are non-null

  - Compare the heads
  - Append to the result the node with the smaller value
  - Advance the head with the smaller value
- Append to the result the head that's non-null

If there are more than 2 lists to merge, apply the algorithm pairwise,
repeatedly until 1 final list remains containing all the lists merged.

In code:

```
Node<K> MergeLists(Node<K> headA, Node<K> headB) {
    Node<K> dummy = new Node<>();
    Node<K> node = dummy;
    while (headA != null && headB != null) {
        if (headA.compareTo(headB) <= 0) {
            node.next = headA;
            headA = headA.next;
        } else {
            node.next = headB;
            headB = headB.next;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }
    if (headA != null) {
        node.next = headA;
    } else {
        node.next = headB;
    }
    return dummy.next;
}
```

Note that this implementation doesn't create a new list of nodes,
but it rewrites the links to form a new linked list.
It can be modified to create a new list if necessary.

#### Organize code for testability

The test data doesn't belong in the constructor of `LinkedListMerge`.
It makes it hard to test the code.
It would be better to create an easy entry point for testing,
for example a method that takes 2 (or more) lists to merge as parameters.